# Sending multiple data in one page Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

[İmage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS1gN.png)

Hello, I want to update multiple data in one page. But when I create a form for each row of textarea, only the first textarea value is updated. How do I do this with jquery? Thank you.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".form").click(function() {
            var text = $("#text").val();
            var id = $("#id").val();
            $.post("../../app/modules/content/update.php", {
                "text": text,
                "id": id
            }, function(cevap) {
                $('#status').html('Güncellendi').show();
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="row">

    <?php
    $query = $veri->selectToplu('contents_temp');
    foreach ($query as $query) { ?>

        <span class="col-md-3 mb-2">
            <div class="card">
                <?php
                if (isset($query['video'])) {
                    echo "<video controls='' style='height: 187px;' src='" . $query['video'] . "' class='bs-card-video'></video>";
                } else {
                    echo "<img class='card-img-top' style='height: 187px;' src='" . $query['img1'] . "'>";
                }
                ?>
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <span deleteid="<?php echo $query['id'] ?>" style="position:absolute; right:0; top:0;" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete">x</span>
                    <form action="" method="POST">
                        <textarea style="height: 7rem" name="text" id="text" class="form-control" col="5" rows="10"><?php echo $query['text'] ?></textarea>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $query['id']; ?>">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-1 form" onclick="buton();">Güncelle</button>
                        <div id="status"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </span>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You need to add some code. Let's see what you've tried.

Comment: @ruleboy21 I edited to topic.

Comment: Do you want the PHP part to generate individual forms so you can submit each one separately or you want just one form with multiple textareas?

Comment: @ruleboy21 Each one is different, each textarea representing a different tweet's description.

Comment: Is each one in a different form or all of them are in the same form?

Comment: @ruleboy21 Is each one in a different form

Comment: Great, so on the server how do you check if the form is submitted?

Comment: $veri = new DB();
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    
    $result = $veri->update('contents_temp', 'text', $text, $id);

    if ($result){
      echo 'Güncellendi';
    }
  }

Comment: I am open to suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove all the `id` attributes from the form inputs. This is because `id` is not unique and won't help much in your case.

Then in your jquery, you use `$(this).find()` to select the submitted form's inputs instead of `$('#element')`. Try this

**PHP/HTML Part**

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
    $query = $veri->selectToplu('contents_temp');
    foreach ($query as $query) { ?>
        <span class="col-md-3 mb-2">
            <div class="card">
                <?php
                if (isset($query['video'])) {
                    echo "<video controls='' style='height: 187px;' src='" . $query['video'] . "' class='bs-card-video'></video>";
                } else {
                    echo "<img class='card-img-top' style='height: 187px;' src='" . $query['img1'] . "'>";
                }
                ?>
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <span deleteid="<?php echo $query['id'] ?>" style="position:absolute; right:0; top:0;" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete">x</span>
                    <form action="" method="POST" class="form">
                        <textarea style="height: 7rem" name="text" class="form-control" col="5" rows="10"><?php echo $query['text'] ?></textarea>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $query['id']; ?>">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-1">Güncelle</button>
                        <div class="status"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </span>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

**jQuery/JavaScript Part**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var text    = $(this).find('[name="text"]').val();
        var id      = $(this).find('[name="id"]').val();
        var $status = $(this).find('.status');

        $.post("../../app/modules/content/update.php", {
            "text": text,
            "id": id
        }, function(cevap) {
            $status.html('Güncellendi').show();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @AnonimTR I've updated my answer, please check if out and let me know if it works.